# Search, and copy paste a text to corresponding file using pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assuming I have a source file containing product price from local shops.

```
$ less SourceFile.txt  # see this file using less function in terminal.
Store Price Dollars
>shop1 >price1 $5
>shop2 >price2 $3
```

And, there are some marketing data called `sub files` for each `Store`, unfortunately not complete.

```
$ less SubFile1.txt  
>owner
TimmyCoLtd
>shop1
grape 

$ less SubFile2.txt 
>shop2
potato
>salesman
John

$ less SubFile3.txt  # no discount information in Source File.
>discount
Nothing
```

Here is the exact output I'd like to see.

```
$ less New.SubFile1.txt  
>owner
TimmyCoLtd
>shop1
grape
>price1
$5 

$ less New.SubFile2.txt 
>shop2
potato
>salesman
John
>price2 
$3

$ less New.SubFile3.txt  # duplicate a same file.
>discount
Nothing
```

If I can find the same `Store` between `Sub File` and `Source File` (all `Store` and `Price` name start with `>` ), then move `Price` and `Dollars` from `Source File` and paste to `Sub File`.

If there is no identical `Store` between `Source File` and `Sub File`, then simply duplicate an identical file for them, such as `New.SubFile3.txt`.

Any good python packages to make it?

Comment: output has to be in the same file or new file? writing to same file is not recommended

Comment: create a new file is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient way is create a dictionary from sourcefile. In dictionary `Id` columns is the key and rest of the columns are values.

```
from pathlib import Path

with open('source_file.txt') as fp:
    next(fp)
    res = dict(line.strip().split(' ', 1) for line in fp)

for file in Path('files').glob('*.txt'):
    with file.open() as fp, open(f'new_{file.stem}.txt', 'w') as fw:
        data = fp.readlines()
        for line in data:
            if line.startswith('>') and line.strip() in res:
                fw.write(''.join(data) + '\n' + '\n'.join(res[line.strip()].split()))
                break
        else:
            fw.writelines(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, I know it will not cost your time too much. However, if I have about 1,000 sub files, can I simply give the path and folder name to replace this line `files = ['sub_file1.txt', 'sub_file2.txt']`

Comment: Is there * between id and data correct?  id, *data = fp.readlines()    my version is 2.7.

Comment: yeah it's there . It's a feature in python3. I have added the link in answer. why are you still using python2?

Comment: well I have been quite long time leaving coding and computer alone.

Comment: `for file in Path(r'F:\').glob("*.txt"):`     like this?  But it still return the same error message.

Comment: backslah is escape character use double backslah or use forwardslash `'F:\\'` or `'F:/'`

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the questions, and deleted the recent similar post. @deadshot

Comment: @Sakura instead of storing the result in subfiles what about using json file where file name is key and data in the file as a list of values?

Comment: Good suggestion, but I never experience with json. Any good way to achieve the output?